# Webpack Dev Server (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' )

Tags: webpack-dev-server

Building TS/SASS with Webpack works fine, running this through VSCode Live Server plugin renders the index.html perfectly to the app folder.

Running webpack-dev-server with it looking at the same app folder does not. The page opens but there is a Javascript error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` 
And the page does not render the JS/CSS.

webpack.config.js

```js
// Imports
var path = require("path");

// Plugins
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

// Exports
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.min.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
  },
  devServer: {
    open: 'http://localhost',
    port: 80,
    publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
    hot: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
    ]
  }, 
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

main.ts

```js
console.log('Main.ts has loaded')
import './styles/main.scss'
```

Any help with this would be appreciated, I'm losing my mind lol.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with syntax in the webpack.config.js file.

I was neglecting to insert a comma at the end of the last entry in every object and array, believing it not to be necessary.

Here is a working config:

```js
// Imports
var path = require("path");

// Plugins
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

// Exports
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  output: {
    filename: 'main.min.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
  },
  devServer: {
    open: 'http://localhost',
    port: 80,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: true },
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ]
      },
    ]
  }, 
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),
  ]
}
```

Comment: "I was neglecting to , the end of the last entry in my objects, believing it not to be necessary." What were you neglecting? I'm having the same issue but I don't understand how you solved it.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. You were neglecting to put a comma after the final element of each object and array in the config. But I don't think this makes any difference, since it's regular JavaScript. Are you sure that's what solved your problem?

Comment: It did seem to do the trick, I'm pretty sure I wasn't doing anything else wrong at the time. But my knowledge of webpack is still quite primitive. Although, looking at it now, it might be the section for resolve and the .ts extentions etc clashing with the path.resolve? I removed that section in my working code. Although now I use config splitting with webpack-merge so I no longer have these sorts of issues.